# How to ensure user processes are killed on logout?

Tags: debian, background-process, logout

I have problem logout on my server (and all debian-derivative servers) do not kill all user processes.

I seem to understand this is done for efficiency reasons for workstations (assumption appears to be same user will log in shortly thereafter).

As an example, on a very restricted account, I get:

```
mcon@cinderella:~$ pgrep --list-full -U gamer
3001599 /lib/systemd/systemd --user
3001600 (sd-pam)
3001615 /usr/bin/pipewire
3001616 /usr/bin/pipewire-media-session
3001624 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --session --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation --syslog-only
3001706 /usr/libexec/gvfsd
3001711 /usr/libexec/gvfsd-fuse /run/user/1002/gvfs -f
3001839 /usr/libexec/dconf-service
3001841 /usr/libexec/gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor
3001852 /usr/libexec/gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor
3001860 /usr/libexec/gvfs-goa-volume-monitor
3001888 /usr/libexec/goa-daemon
3001906 /usr/libexec/goa-identity-service
3001908 /usr/libexec/gvfs-mtp-volume-monitor
3001915 /usr/libexec/gvfs-afc-volume-monitor
3002093 /usr/libexec/evolution-source-registry
3002108 /usr/libexec/gvfsd-trash --spawner :1.9 /org/gtk/gvfs/exec_spaw/0
3002112 /usr/libexec/xdg-desktop-portal
3002120 /usr/libexec/xdg-document-portal
3002124 /usr/libexec/xdg-permission-store
3002132 fusermount3 -o rw,nosuid,nodev,fsname=portal,auto_unmount,subtype=portal -- /run/user/1002/doc
3002150 /usr/libexec/evolution-calendar-factory
3002162 /usr/libexec/gvfsd-metadata
3002176 /usr/libexec/evolution-addressbook-factory
3002227 /usr/libexec/bluetooth/obexd
3002924 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/share/system-config-printer/applet.py
3827100 /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --start --foreground --components=secrets
```

This was taken (many) hours user `gamer` has logged off and after other users (including myself) used the system.

I have seen [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74063/kill-user-processess-on-logout) but that doesn't apply to my case: I do **not** want to prevent users from explicitly starting long-running processes via `nohup` or `screen`, but simply kill all "useless" system tasks.

I tried setting `[Login]` -> `KillUserProcesses=yes` in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` but apparently nothing changed.

Note all those processes remain active for each user that ever logged in (since last reboot, of course).

How do I get rid of all those processes?
Is it really needed to run some `cron` script to kill them?
If so: how do I separate "explicitly wanted" background processes from system cruft?

P.S.: I know StackExchange policy is "one question mark per OP", but these are really various aspects of the same question.

Comment: @ArtemS.TashkinovI did a `systemctl daemon-reload` but that was *not* enough, for some reason. A full reboot did the trick. Thanks.

Comment: See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1871726

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reboot or `sudo systemctl daemon-reexec`. daemon-reload only reloads units, thus it won't work.